# Combining JavaScript Objects in Couchdb

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

I have this **Couchdb** view that doesn't do what I expect. It doesn't add `code`, `balance` and `session` to `params`:

```
function(doc) {
    var params = doc.initial_url_params; //This is an object with many properties
    params["code"] = doc.code;
    params["balance"] = doc.balance;
    params["session"] = doc.session.session_id;
    emit(doc.code, params);
}
```

On the other hand, this other implementation does the trick:

```
function(doc) {
    var params = {};
    params["code"] = doc.code;
    params["balance"] = doc.balance;
    params["session"] = doc.session.session_id;
    for (prop in doc.initial_url_params) {
        params[prop] = doc.initial_url_params[prop];
    }
    emit(doc.code, params);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why these two implementations aren't equivalent? Am I doing something stupid with Javascript or is it some specific limitation of Couchdb's Javascript implementation?

For the sake of clarity. Here is a sample json doc:

```
{
   "_id": "207112eaaad136dca7b0b7b1c6356dc4",
   "_rev": "3-e02de1f2f269642df98ab19ee023569b",
   "session_loaded": true,
   "balance": 20.48,
   "code": "05428",
   "initial_url_params": {
       "page_id": "212"
   },
   "session": {
       "session_id": "207112eaaad136dca7b0b7b1c6356dc4",
       "init": true
   }
}
```

Comment: just for the sake of clarity, can you give a sample of the doc.initial_url_params object data?

Comment: Maybe `initial_url_params` is [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)/[sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)?

Comment: Aha!!! Maybe this is it. Thanks Fabricio, perhaps doc is frozen: http://grokbase.com/t/couchdb/user/08cjddzrwd/adding-attributes-to-a-document-in-the-view If you wish, please convert your comment into a reply so that I can assign this as the correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in your 2 samples is that `initial_url_params` is a property of an already defined object `doc`, which may have been [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) before being passed to your function. As such, you can't add new properties to it, but you are still able to read and iterate over these to build a new (unfrozen) object.

And this seems to be the case according to OP's [linked thread](http://grokbase.com/t/couchdb/user/08cjddzrwd/adding-attributes-to-a-document-in-the-view).

---

In JavaScript, objects are passed by reference so if properties were to be added to the `doc` object, all other functions that operate on it would also be able to see those non-standard properties and possibly break some map functions.

Here's a vanilla JS example of the paragraph above:

```
var doc = { foo: true };
function a(doc) { doc.bar = 1; }
function b(doc) { console.log(doc); }
a(doc);
b(doc); // outputs: { foo: true, bar: 1 }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HThb/) - in the above example, `b` would expect to see only the originally defined properties in `doc`, but `a` has modified it as objects are passed by reference. This is an overly simplistic representation, but you can see where this may lead when a function attempts to map the object's properties to other logic.